# Hibernate Get List<String> of a table's attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

Hello everybody and sorry for the rather confusing question-title.

I have a Hibernate Class configured using Annotations. This class has a String-attribute which contains the name of a company.

What i need is to get a list of these String-attributes without needing to get all objects that contain the attribute.

Is this possible using Criteria?

Example:

```
class Company {
    Customer customer;
    String companyName;
}
```

So I'd need a list with all companyName-Values and not a List of Company-Objects.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Best Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not accourding to this link: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=947652&view=next

Comment: actually it seems that it works according to the last post in the thread: criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("companyName"));  Thanks for the link :)